# How to taggle dropdowns menus without overlapping each other in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular13

I'm new to angular. I have created 3 menu dropdowns in header namely language menu, message preview menu, and user menu. I used class binding and attribute binding concepts in the view

If I click on language menu - html attribute "open" is adding up in the html to show the language menu items. At the same time I need to close other menu(message preview menu and/or user menu) if they are opened already.

I used class binding and attribute binding concepts in the html view

header.component.html

```
<nav class="main-navigation-grid-item">

<!-- language menu -->

    <details   [open]="showLanguageMenu"
      class="--languageSelection flyoutmenu-relative-section">
      <summary (click)="toggleLanguageFlyout()">
        <span class="title">
          <span class="longLabel">{{selectedLanguage.label}}</span>
          {{selectedLanguage.isoLabel}}
        </span>
      </summary>
      <ul class="--languageSelectionOptions flyoutmenu-container arrow-top open">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let item of languageLocales; trackBy: identifyCurrentElement">
          <li>
            <label class="radioButton"
              [ngClass]="{'disabled':selectedLanguage.active && (item.languageLocale == selectedLanguage.languageLocale)}">
              <input type="radio"
                (attr.disabled)="selectedLanguage.active && (item.languageLocale == selectedLanguage.languageLocale)"
                (ngModelChange)="updateLanguage($event)"
                [value]=item
                [(ngModel)]="activeLanguageLocale"
                name="languageSelection">
              <span class="label">
                <span class="longLabel">{{item.label}}</span>{{item.isoLabel}}
              </span>
            </label>
          </li>
        </ng-container>
      </ul>
    </details>

    <ul class="--primaryNavigation">

<!-- message preview menu -->

      <li class="flyoutmenu-relative-section">
        <button class="--messagePreview flyout-button"
          (click)="toggleMessagePreviewFlyout()"
          [attr.aria-label]="'Notifications:'+ dummyMessages.length"
          [attr.data-notification-count]="dummyMessages.length">
          <span class="icon-liebherr-my-notifier-icon-rgb-64px"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="--messagePreviewContent flyoutmenu-container arrow-top"
          (click)="goToMessageSection()"
          [ngClass]="{'open':messagePreviewFlyoutIsOpen}">
          <ng-container *ngFor="let message of dummyMessages">
            <li>
              <span class="from">{{message.sender}}</span>
              <div class="when">{{message.when}}</div>
              <span class="message">{{message.message}}</span>
            </li>
          </ng-container>
        </ul>
      </li>

<!-- user menu  -->

      <li class="flyoutmenu-relative-section">
        <a class="current-user" (click)="showUserMenuOnClick()">LB</a>
        <div class="flyoutmenu-container arrow-top" [style.display]="showFlyoutMenu ? 'block' : 'none'">
          <div class="flyoutmenu-user-section">
            <div class="flyoutmenu-avatar-container">
              <div class="flyoutmenu-current-avatar">LB</div>
            </div>
            <div class="flyoutmenu-current-user-info-section">
              <span class="flyoutmenu-user-name">John Doe</span>
              <span class="flyoutmenu-user-info">Liebherr</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

header.component.ts

```
languageLocales = [
    {
      languageLocale: "en_US",
      label: "USA",
      isoLabel: "EN",
      active: false
    },
    {
      languageLocale: "it_IT",
      label: "Italiano",
      isoLabel: "IT",
      active: false
    },

  ]
  activeLanguageLocale: Object = {dataSource: this.languageLocales[0]};
  initialLanguage = {
    languageLocale: "en_US",
    label: "USA",
    isoLabel: "EN",
    active: true
  };
  selectedLanguage = this.initialLanguage;
  //----------------------------------------------- DEMO DATA: notification messages
  dummyMessages = [
    {
      when: "20 seconds ago",
      sender: "Julia Marketing",
      message: "Consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, molestiae voluptatum. Aperiam assumenda commodi deleniti dolore.",
    },
    {
      when: "3 minutes ago",
      sender: "Marius Support",
      message: "Libero magni numquam perspiciatis porro praesentium totam. Architecto autem dolor est iure molestiae odio."
    }
  ]
  //----------------------------------------------- VARS FOR MENU TOGGLING
  showFlyoutMenu: boolean = false;
  showLanguageMenu: boolean = false;
  messagePreviewFlyoutIsOpen: boolean = false;
  showAppLauncher: boolean = false;
  tab: any = 'tab1';
  togglemenu: boolean = false;
  status: boolean = false;
  notificationCount: any = 0;


  identifyCurrentElement(index: number, item: any) {
    return item;
  }


  constructor(public router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
 
  }

  closeAllMenus(){
    this.messagePreviewFlyoutIsOpen = false;
    this.showAppLauncher = false;
    this.showFlyoutMenu = false;
    if(document.getElementsByClassName("--languageSelection")[0].hasAttribute("open")){
      this.showLanguageMenu = true;
    }else{
      this.showLanguageMenu = false;
      console.log("languagemenu",this.showLanguageMenu)
    }
  }

  showUserMenuOnClick() {
    this.closeAllMenus();
    this.showFlyoutMenu =true;
    console.log(this.showLanguageMenu);
  }

  toggleLanguageFlyout() {
    this.closeAllMenus();
    console.log(this.showLanguageMenu);
  }

  toggleMessagePreviewFlyout() {
    debugger
    this.closeAllMenus();
    this.messagePreviewFlyoutIsOpen = true;
    console.log(this.showLanguageMenu);
  }


  goToMessageSection() {
    alert('should open messages section');
  }

  updateLanguage($e: any) {
    console.log($e);
    this.selectedLanguage = $e;
    this.selectedLanguage.active = true;
    return this.selectedLanguage;
  }
```

Now actually other menu's are overlapping

[image: Reference Screenshot]

How to write a condition that when I open one menu and rest other opened menu should close.

Comment: It would be best if you listened to the events and code so that you could track the open menu items. I suggest not using native query selectors and instead using `ViewChild` from Angular to get the template reference. I see that you have used the 'active' property to track the open menu item. You can use initially mark everything as false and based on the selection set the object's prop to true. The code actually looks a little messy and I'm unable to properly go through it. Can you attach a stackblitz link to your project?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using *ngIf in your HTML file :

```
// in the parent element of eache of your menu, you have to define 3 strings as I've done with 'language'
<ul class="--primaryNavigation" *ngIf="openedMenu === 'language'">
```

And then in your ts file, add a openedMenu property :

```
public openedMenu = 'language'; // or other value

// and toggle the wanted menu, 'language' for example
public toggleLanguageMenu() : void {
  this.openedMenu = 'language';
}
```